# I seem to have problems extracting URLs within each unique webpage

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

"Hello all, am quite new to webscraping. I am intending to extract URLs based on a list of unique URLs that are categorised according to years (1919-2019)."

"With assistance, I am able to parse the URLs to retrieve the links but the links i am getting do not work"

"code is shown below"

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}
main_url = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/"

def get_and_parse_url(main_url):
    result = s.get(main_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
    data_table = [main_url + i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href*=Year]')]
    return data_table

with requests.Session() as s:
    data_table = get_and_parse_url(main_url)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_table, columns=['url'])
    datatable2 = [] #create outside so can append to it

    for anker in df.url:
        result = s.get(anker, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
        datatable2.append(['https://aviation-safety.net' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href*="database/record"]')])

 #flatten list of lists
datatable2 = [i for sublist in datatable2 for i in sublist]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(datatable2 , columns=['add_url'])
print(df2)
```

"However, the links generated in my output are https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.ph... where the page cannot be found" "I am not sure why this is so"

"I'm hoping to get links https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19190802-0 all the way to https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=20190801-0"

"any form of help is much appreciated, thank you!"

Comment: code is fine. Dont go over `print(df2)` . Try this and you will see that links are fine
`for i in df2.add_url:
     print(i)`

Comment: @UpasanaMittal, this works, thank you!. How would i save 'i' in a dataframe then?

Comment: Dataframe is fine. You can export it by `df2.to_csv(filepath)` to csv and check.